# Obtaining user signature on local server using Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have flask application that runs only locally on a windows 10 tablet. Staff members fill out the form answering a series of questions and submit the form. Now I need to obtain the user's signature on the form web page. I don't have to validate the signature against some database, so all I need to do is save the signature.

Hence, I have been looking to see if flask-wtforms had something pre-built, but I did not find anything. So I was planning on using tkinter which opens up a box in the web page where the user can sign their signature on the tablet. However, I wanted the signature to be writable on the web page itself (maybe some kind of field where user can write their signature with a stylus on the tablet screen) just using python/flask. I would like to avoid having to open up a second box for the user to sign. Any suggestions?